# how to replace original image with another image in runtime in using pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make application which can show weather net is down or up with graphical representation. For the task I am using pyqt5, But when I am trying to do it, it just overlap on same image again and again.

```
time2 = ""
class DigitalClock(QLCDNumber, QWidget):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DigitalClock, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Digital Clock")
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.mainlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.ui)
        timer.start(1000)
        self.ui()
        self.show()

    def ui(self):
        global time2
        time = QTime.currentTime()
        text = time.toString('hh:mm')
        if (time.second() % 2) == 0:
           text = text[:2]+" "+ text[3:]


        if text[3:] != time2:
            if os.system("ping -c 1 192.168.63.145") == 0:
                self.network = QLabel(self)
                self.network.setPixmap(QPixmap("signal-bars.png"))
                self.network.move(50,300)
                self.network.show()
                time2 = text[3:]
            else:
                self.network = QLabel(self)
                self.network.setPixmap(QPixmap("no-internet.png"))
                time2 = text[3:]
            self.network.move(50,300)
            self.network.show()
        self.display(text)




def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    clock = DigitalClock()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

QLCDNumber Class - Inherits:    QFrame.

QFrame Class - Inherits:    QWidget.

No need to create each time - `self.network = QLabel (self)`.

You do not need `global` variables.

Try it:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


#time2 = ""

class DigitalClock(QLCDNumber):                            #, QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DigitalClock, self).__init__(parent)

        self.time2 = True                                   # +
        self.network = QLabel(self)                         # +
        self.network.setGeometry(50, 300, 150, 150)         # +

        self.setWindowTitle("Digital Clock")
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.mainlayout = QHBoxLayout()                     # ?

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.ui)
        self.ui()
        timer.start(1000)

    def ui(self):
#        global time2                                        # ---
        time = QTime.currentTime()
        text = time.toString('hh:mm')
        if (time.second() % 2) == 0:
           text = text[:2]+" "+ text[3:]


#        if text[3:] != time2:
#            if os.system("ping -c 1 192.168.63.145") == 0:
        if self.time2:
#            self.network = QLabel(self)                      # ---
            self.network.setPixmap(QPixmap("im.png").scaled(150, 150, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)) 
#            time2 = text[3:]
        else:
#            self.network = QLabel(self)
            self.network.setPixmap(QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(150, 150, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
#            time2 = text[3:]

        self.time2 = not self.time2

        self.display(text)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    clock = DigitalClock()
    clock.show()                      # +
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: There's no problem using `super` since PyQt5 has good [support for co-operative multi-inheritance](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/multiinheritance.html). Including `parent=None` in the `__init__` signature is standard practice and allows for code re-use. The use of `QApplication(sys.argv)` is also standard practice and enables [Qt-specific commandline options](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication). If you have more complex requirements, use [QCommandLineParser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html).

Comment: @DennisJensen - I am new to pyqt5 just give-up with tkinter. Trying my best to get use to.